# Should SubsetMap be called CombineAt?

Tags: language-design

I'm a big fan of the functionality introduced by `SubsetMap` but am puzzled as to why it was not called "`CombineAt`". There are multiple reasons:

1. **Indicative:** *Combining* the elements of a given expression at given positions seems to capture what it does more so than the apparently more obscure `SubsetMap` (initially I could never remember the function's name until I substituted `CombineAt=SubsetMap` in my initialisation). It seems to capture the "in place" transformation by connoting the fact that the supplied function needs to return a list with the same length as the positions specified.
2. **Linguistic:** The respective, linguistic operator form "I'm going to use *f* to `CombineAt` *pos* in *expr* seems more active than the more passive (and awkward) "I'm going to `SubsetMap` *f* at *pos* in *expr*.
3. **Generality:** `CombineAt` captures the function's full generality since it indicates operate on *any* expression at *any* position. Contrast this with the family of `Subset` functions `SubsetCases`, `SubsetPosition`, `SubsetReplace`, `SubsetCount` (that it is clearly being linked to) that only operate on lists.
4. **Avoids inconsistency and misleading connections**: The whole point of the `Subset*` functions is that order is not important as they distinguish from ordered analogies `SequenceCases`, `SequencePosition`, `SequenceReplace`, `SequenceCount`. In contrast, there is no notion of orderlessness in `SubsetMap` since positions are explicitly specified (not to mention no "`SequenceMap`" analogue). Further, `Map` has a specific meaning in the WL that seems to have no bearing on its more mathematical use in this function.
5. **Consistency:** `CombineAt` seems much more closely related to `MapAt`'s functionality (while `ParallelCombine` supports the specification of a "combining" function).

So my question is this: what are the reasons *for* the `SubsetMap` name?

Comment: Indeed, something with an `At` at the end might have been more meaningful. Well, I am pretty sure that I know who picked this name and that this person does not roam these rooms. So I do not really understand the purpose of this question. If you mean to suggest a renaming then you should better contact support.

Comment: Well that is (only) part of the purpose of this question. The availability of a "language-design" tag suggests to me that it is fair game to seek reasons "for" the original naming (that I could well have overlooked). Actually I did suggest this prior to V12.1's release (when it was tagged experimental) and am curious about naming in general and the community's take.

Comment: I know from watching the livestreams that WRI anguished over the naming of `SubsetMap`.  Personally, I liked `ApplyAt` (as the best of a bad bunch).  `SubsetMap` does not really fit in with the other new subset functions `SubsetReplace`, `SubsetCases`, `SubsetCount`, etc.

Comment: @WReach  I wasn't aware of the livestream - do you have the episode by any chance? I agree that `SubsetMap` seems oddly out of place with the new subset functions and this is tacitly acknowledged if you look at the "See Also" linkages in the Help Documentation: `SubsetReplace`->`SubsetMap` being one of the few. `ApplyAt` while containing the more apt "At",  similarly suffers because of the specific history/meaning of `Apply` which confuses the generic meaning with WL's explicitness. The combine in `CombineAt` otoh doesn't have this baggage with the combine also capturing its "in-placeness".

Comment: @RonaldMonson I took a quick look through the [livestreams list](https://www.stephenwolfram.com/livestreams/), but I was not able to locate one of the relevant episodes.  My recollection is that there were several discussions about it right before the 12.0 release... so late 2018/early 2019.  In one episode the discussion was quite long with many suggestions given in the stream chat on Twitch.  Sorry I can't be more specific, but there are a lot of recorded videos and I know no easy way to scan their content.  I _think_ it would have been one of the "Language Design" sessions.

Comment: @WReach Ok, thanks, no worries; Apparently there are some WL functions/APIs that can be used to search this archive - don't have time right now but perhaps will road-test these with this particular example.